# Django filter with keyword arguments and a NOT condition

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-1.9

I've got these keyword arguments that I pass into a Django `filter()` -

```
kwargs = {'field_1': val_1,
          'field_2': val_2}
```

However I also want to pass in a `NOT` check, for example, `field_3 is NOT val_3`.

I know I can do that using a `Q` object but I would like to know if I can somehow accomplish that using a keyword argument.

The reason I'm asking is that there is already a code written by one of my colleagues that constructs the `kwargs` parameters according to passed-in arguments, and filters the Django queryset. I would like to use the same code without having to write a separate one if I can help it.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `.exclude()`?

Comment: Yes, actually that's fine. I was so fixated on the keyword arguments that I forgot the good-old `.exclude()`. Thanks!